# Is it possible to change freeswitch user password on hot?

Tags: password, login, freeswitch

Is it possible to change freeswitch user password on hot? I mean I have freeswitch running and wish to change 1000's password from 1234 to something else without restarting freeswitch?

I an changing `conf/directory/default/1000.xml` now and then issuing `xmlreload` command.

This causes new users unable to log in, but old connected users seem to stay logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change a user's directory entry without restarting FreeSWITCH. After you edit the 1000.xml file, save it, then go to fs_cli and press F6 or issue the command: `reloadxml`. At that point, all future auth challenges will require the new password. If you have old registrations that you want to clear out just use the sofia command:

```
sofia profile internal flush_inbound_reg
```

Then force your SIP device to re-register.